# angular-json-schema-form not working properly with .net Bundleconfig?

Tags: .net, angular, angular6, angular7, angular6-json-schema-form

I am trying to use the npm package "angular6-json-schema-form". I do have the "@angular/flex-layout" package that is required and i do run Angular 7 and bootstrap 4 . I do bundle the angular produced files with the .net Frameworks bundleconfig.cs .

```
        bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/AccountingClientAppVM")
            .Include("~/Areas/ClientApp/build/accounting/vendor.js")
            .Include("~/Areas/ClientApp/build/accounting/main.js"));
```

I do get this error when running the application. Even though the angular build goes through with no errors.
[image]

When I run the Angular build in prod mode. it seems to work and it do find the bundle . the angular json-schema does also work in that case. Its odd as the production build is strickter and why should minification impact this. I would like some help if anyone knows something about this issue.

Comment: maybe, the build path is wrong?. did you physically verify the files?

Comment: yes i have checked that the files exist in that path and it works fine when i dont use that npm package.